# Twilio not sending SMS in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5, twilio

Using this code:

```
use App\Helpers\Helper;

  public function send_otp(Request $request)
    {

      $phone      = "+".$request->mobile; 
        $checkPhone = User::where('mobile', $phone)->first();

    if(count($checkPhone) == 0) {
            $six_digit_random_number = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
            $message    = "Your one time verification code is $six_digit_random_number"; 
            Helper::send_twilio_sms($phone, $message);
            $response_array = array('success'=>true,'code'=>$six_digit_random_number,'message'=>'OTP Code has been sent succesfully');
        } else {
            $response_array = array('success'=>false,'code'=>'','message'=>'The mobile number is in already use.');
        }

       $response = response()->json($response_array, 200);
       return $response;
}
```

The SMS is not sending and the mobile app is not getting the message.

Comment: store `Helper::send_twilio_sms($phone, $message)` in to variable and see what's return value.

Comment: Can you post `Helper::send_twilio_sms($phone, $message)` function here?

Comment: Is there any reason why you added the `Android` tag? Because I can't see anything related to Android development.

Comment: @lulian basically this is for android app and we need expert advice of this field as well if there is any issue